# Implement modal-box in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, tooltip

Using the qtip2-plugin i created a tool tip:

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8383/

If you click on the image in the tooltip, a modalbox display´s.

In this modalbox the image should be displayed, but it isnt.

I think that´s the wrong code:

```
<img src='{{{img}}}' alt='image error' class='profilep' />  // the src-tag
```

But i dont know what to put there instead, anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declared the first part of your template outside of your script tag. Mustache wasn't replacing anything and your image had an src attribute of `{{{img}}}`

This:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <img src='{{{img}}}' alt='image error' class='profilep' />
    </div>
</div>

<script id="tooltipContent" type="text/html">
    <a href='#openModal'><img src='{{{img}}}' alt='error' class='picture' /></a>
    <p class='text'><a href="#">{{text}}</a></p>
</script>
```

should be:

```
<script id="tooltipContent" type="text/html">
  <a href='#openModal'><img src='{{{img}}}' alt='error' class='picture' /></a>
  <p class='text'><a href="#">{{text}}</a></p>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <img src='{{{img}}}' alt='image error' class='profilep' />
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/AJ8Sa/).